# How to check if a key value is or is not in a defaultdict(list) within an If-statement's logic

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

I have a matching script that daily looks a  list if unique IDS in a pandas dataframe and then takes their address info and compares the address info to another DF using a series of matching algorithms. The Good results are put into a defaultdict(list) where the unique IDs are the dict keys and the results are items.

Sometimes there are matches that arent found between the two dataframes and so I created a separate defaultdict(list) that stores these bad matches.  Ive created a series of "tests" that determine if the match is good or not. My thought was that anything that doesnt get populated in the first defaultdict(list) I could use a "if not in" statement to capture the missing info.

**In my example, ID 666666 is considered a bad match, and should not be added to test_dic_stack but added to test_dic_stack_bad_match because the scores are LOW**

**Goal:** *Capture all IDS that are bad matches and bring them to test_dic_stack_bad_match  *

After I append all my data to the good defaultdict(list) id still like to look at the remaining unique IDS, incase I didnt have any matches. I have an if statement that looks at the ID to see if its not in the defaultdict(list).. If its not there then I have it perform some logic, however, my BAD data isnt getting picked up by this if statement and Im not sure why not.

**Here's a preview of the data:**

```
#imports
from collections import defaultdict
from fuzzywuzzy import process, fuzz 
import Levenshtein as lev
from pyjarowinkler import distance

#variables 
test_dic_stack = defaultdict(list)
test_dic_stack_bad_match = defaultdict(list)

#logic used to get the testing data (not full code, I can copy but its very long)
#           lev_score = round(lev.ratio(Account_Address, Address_match) * 100,0)
#             fuzz_score = fuzz.token_set_ratio(Account_Address, Address_match)
#             jaro_test = distance.get_jaro_distance(Account_Address, Address_match) * 100  

#             if  fuzz_score >= 85  and jaro_test >= 90:
#                 match_quality = 1
#             elif fuzz_score >= 80 
#                 match_quality = 2       
#             elif fuzz_score >= 65 and jaro_test >= 75:
#                 match_quality = 3                   
#             elif fuzz_score >= 30:
#                 match_quality = 4
                
#             elif fuzz_score < 30:
#                 match_quality = 5
              
            
#             if match_quality == 4 or match_quality == 5:
#                 continue       
#             else:
#                 test_dic_stack.append()
#here is where the appending happens. Then afterwards I have the not-if-statement to "capture" the bad results.


#testing data 
test_dic_stack['111111'].append({'Account Name': 'company1', 'Matching Account': 'company1', 'Account_Address': '123 Road', 'Address_match': '123 Road',  'Lev_score': 98.0, 'Fuzzy_score': 100, 'Jaro_Score': 99.0})
test_dic_stack['222222'].append({'Account Name': 'company1', 'Matching Account': 'company1', 'Account_Address': '1 awesome street', 'Address_match': '1 awesome street',  'Lev_score': 91.0, 'Fuzzy_score': 89, 'Jaro_Score': 99.0})
test_dic_stack['333333'].append({'Account Name': 'company2', 'Matching Account': 'company2', 'Account_Address': '1 awesome street', 'Address_match': '1 awesome st',  'Lev_score': 71.0, 'Fuzzy_score': 82, 'Jaro_Score': 84.0})
test_dic_stack['444444'].append({'Account Name': 'company3', 'Matching Account': 'company3', 'Account_Address': '1 awesome street', 'Address_match': '1 awesome street suite 1',  'Lev_score': 88.0, 'Fuzzy_score': 89, 'Jaro_Score': 90.0})
test_dic_stack['555555'].append({'Account Name': 'company4', 'Matching Account': 'company4', 'Account_Address': '1 awesome street', 'Address_match': '1 awe street',  'Lev_score': 81.0, 'Fuzzy_score': 90, 'Jaro_Score': 86.0})

#in my script this 666666 match wouldnt get appended but I put it here as an illustrative. 
#The ID would exist in the dataframe still, but it wouldnt be in test_dic_stack
#(AND so it should be getting picked up by the "if not in" statement??
test_dic_stack['666666'].append({'Account Name': 'company5', 'Matching Account': 'companyTZT', 'Account_Address': '1 awesome street', 'Address_match': '555 state road',  'Lev_score': 30.0, 'Fuzzy_score': 30, 'Jaro_Score': 49.0})

#defaultdict preview
defaultdict(list,
            {'111111': [{'Account Name': 'company1',
               'Matching Account': 'company1',
               'Account_Address': '123 Road',
               'Address_match': '123 Road',
               'Lev_score': 98.0,
               'Fuzzy_score': 100,
               'Jaro_Score': 99.0}],
             '222222': [{'Account Name': 'company1',
               'Matching Account': 'company1',
               'Account_Address': '1 awesome street',
               'Address_match': '1 awesome street',
               'Lev_score': 91.0,
               'Fuzzy_score': 89,
               'Jaro_Score': 99.0}],
             '333333': [{'Account Name': 'company2',
               'Matching Account': 'company2',
               'Account_Address': '1 awesome street',
               'Address_match': '1 awesome st',
               'Lev_score': 71.0,
               'Fuzzy_score': 82,
               'Jaro_Score': 84.0}],
             '444444': [{'Account Name': 'company3',
               'Matching Account': 'company3',
               'Account_Address': '1 awesome street',
               'Address_match': '1 awesome street suite 1',
               'Lev_score': 88.0,
               'Fuzzy_score': 89,
               'Jaro_Score': 90.0}],
             '555555': [{'Account Name': 'company4',
               'Matching Account': 'company4',
               'Account_Address': '1 awesome street',
               'Address_match': '1 awe street',
               'Lev_score': 81.0,
               'Fuzzy_score': 90,
               'Jaro_Score': 86.0}],
             '666666': [{'Account Name': 'company5',
               'Matching Account': 'companyTZT',
               'Account_Address': '1 awesome street',
               'Address_match': '555 state road',
               'Lev_score': 30.0,
               'Fuzzy_score': 30,
               'Jaro_Score': 49.0}]})
```

**Here's my requested result:**
#I would expect '666666' to be in this section here

```
if number not in test_dic_stack:
     then do something and add results to test_dic_stack_bad_match 
# 666666 had bad matches so do something with it here
```

Answer (score 0):

So I noticed that my "not if in"statement wasnt working. I also had logic that if a match didnt fit a specific criteria that it was getting passed over with a "continue" statement. So what I did was I used sets. I took a set of the result of the "good matches" and compared it with the result of all the "customer supplier numbers" Once I had that difference I could then consider those as "bad matches"